# Estimating binomial distribution from small sample

Tags: confidence-interval, binomial-distribution

I have a set of 9000 outcomes and I wish to make an estimate (with 95% confidence interval) of the amount of 'positive' examples.
After viewing 413 examples I found 13 positives (positive rate of 13/413 = 0.0315). With a cumulative binomial distribution I can make an estimate of the total positives with a 95% confidence interval.

However, the calculated positive rate is based on a small sample and addition of another single positive example can shift the 95% confidence interval by a large amount. How can I incorporate the size of my sample into the estimate so it is more robust?

My matlab code:

```
N_found = 14;
N_excl = 400;
N_tot=9000;
binoinv([0.05 0.95],N_tot-N_found-N_excl,N_found/(N_found+N_excl))+N_found
```

Comment: If you go from 13 positive to 14 positive cases, the interval *should* shift substantially -- the point estimate will increase by a multiple of nearly 14/13 (i.e. up by about 7.5%)

Answer (score 2):

To get a 95% confidence interval (or an interval of any confidence level) for a binomial parameter $p$ you can use the Clopper-Pearson method. This method delivers "exact" confidence intervals; by "exact" I mean a confidence interval that has a confidence level exactly equal to the pre-specified value.

You can look at Hahn and Meeker's **Statistical Intervals: A Guide for Practitioners**, First Edition, Wiley 1991.

Comment: Are you suggesting "exact" means "robust"?

Comment: @whuber No exact means that is has the exact confidence level specified.

Comment: Then how does this respond to the question?  It asks for "robust" solutions and it makes it clear what it means by "robust."

Comment: Should I use the lower and upper proportion values in my estimate and run it twice? And then take the upper and lower bounds of both answers?

Comment: For a two-sided confidence interval the upper and lower bounds that you get initially are the appropriate ones.  You do not need to do this twice. Also you asked for a robust solution. The solution gives you exactly 95% coverage and there is no need for robustness.

Comment: This doesn't work since the 95% interval does not take into account how many instances are left. However, by running my original algorithm twice (once with lower p and upper p estimates) I do get a relatively stable estimate which converges as N increases. Problem with using only the p-values is that at the end it estimates e.g. 240 positves as lower bound while I already found 260, by double-running it, the lower bound of the total positives is set at 262 for example.

Comment: One almost never gets "exactly" the nominal coverage, Michael, because the distribution is discrete.  Intervals for rare proportions are particularly problematic in this regard.  I checked Hahn & Meeker (first edition, pp 103-108) and could not find any claim there that this is an exact procedure.